# how can I solve mPeakPower issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have 2 issues

1) when I run the code it will give me exc_bad_access in this line

```
Float32 peak = levels[0].mPeakPower;
```

2) when I run an animation it will give me this error and after that, the App crashes:

```
cocos2d: CCTexture2D. Can't create Texture. `UIImage` is nil
2011-08-02 12:38:14.921 AnimBear[596:207] cocos2d: Couldn't add
image:face.plist in CCTextureCache
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: 2) Please post some code, and also make sure the correct image, I think 1) may be related to a nil reference because of 2?

Comment: [listenerNew pause];
 [listenerNew listen]; // Quick.
 
 // Or free up resources when we're not listening for awhile.
 [listenerNew stop];
 [listenerNew listen]; // Slower.
 AudioQueueLevelMeterState *levels = [listenerNew levels];
 Float32 peak = levels[0].mPeakPower;

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/ code of bear

Comment: It appears you have two separate problems. Neither are adequately described with code. #1 is simple, for some reason levels[0].mPeakPower is empty. Why, we can't tell yet. The same is true for #2, only for a different reason, namely that face.plist is not an image.

Comment: I solve my problem thnx for helping me in this matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your levels array is likely nil or empty (the access to item 0 is causing the exception).  You might log [levels count] ahead of that line to confirm the length of the array.

```
NSLog(@"Levels count: %d", [levels count]);
```

For the second part of the question, face.plist is not an image.  Typically loading a sprite using a texture cache looks like:

```
CCTexture2D *texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:imageName];
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:texture];
```